# Customer DOB in subscribers list

Tags: magento-1.7, custom, database

I have a problem for which I cannot find the right answer.
In Magento I want to add the DOB to the newsletter-subscribers.
I successfully did, by following this tutorial:

http://www.iamrookie.com/blog/159/add-custo-field-in-newsletter-module-magento.html

So now I see a DOB-row in my database and in my backend from Magento. And if I set a date in the database (I’m not testing with the sign-up form) I see the right value.

The only thing I want to do is to check of the customer has set an DOB in his profile. If so, I want to override the value in the database with his DOB.

This should be possible because you also see the first and last name of the customer in the backend.

I believe the file where I should change it is the subscriber.php. I tried different thing already, but nothing is working.

I think I should do something here......

```
 /**
 * Load subscriber info by customer
 *
 * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer
 * @return Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
 */
public function loadByCustomer(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
{
    $data = $this->getResource()->loadByCustomer($customer);
    $this->addData($data);
    if (!empty($data) && $customer->getId() && !$this->getCustomerId()) {
        $this->setCustomerId($customer->getId());

        $this->setSubscriberConfirmCode($this->randomSequence());
        if ($this->getStatus()==self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
            $this->setStatus($customer->getIsSubscribed() ? self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED : self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED);
        }
        $this->save();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

or here:

```
 /**
 * Retrieve Subscribers Full Name if it was set
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getSubscriberFullName()
{
    $name = null;
    if ($this->hasCustomerFirstname() || $this->hasCustomerLastname()) {
        $name = $this->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $this->getCustomerLastname();
    }
    return $name;
}
```

But I really don’t know. If somebody has any idea how to get this done, I really would appreciate it!

Comment: Are you trying to override the DOB displayed on the customer's profile with the DOB entered into the subscription field?  Or are you trying to override the DOB in the subscription DOB with the one in the customer's profile if it isn't initially entered in the subscribe field?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Both. Depending on which is updated last. But I would prefer the last one. But maybe I will be just fine with a way to display the DOB of customers in the grid, like the first and last name.

Answer (score 1):

The first and last name are added from `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Resource_Subscriber_Collection::showCustomerInfo()`.

You can rewrite that method and add something similar for the dob.

```
public function showCustomerInfo()
{
    $adapter = $this->getConnection();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $firstname  = $customer->getAttribute('firstname');
    $lastname   = $customer->getAttribute('lastname');
    $dob        = $customer->getAttribute('dob');

    $this->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            array('customer_lastname_table'=>$lastname->getBackend()->getTable()),
            $adapter->quoteInto('customer_lastname_table.entity_id=main_table.customer_id
             AND customer_lastname_table.attribute_id = ?', (int)$lastname->getAttributeId()),
            array('customer_lastname'=>'value')
        )
        ->joinLeft(
            array('customer_firstname_table'=>$firstname->getBackend()->getTable()),
            $adapter->quoteInto('customer_firstname_table.entity_id=main_table.customer_id
             AND customer_firstname_table.attribute_id = ?', (int)$firstname->getAttributeId()),
            array('customer_firstname'=>'value')
        )
        ->joinLeft(
            array('customer_dob_table'=>$dob->getBackend()->getTable()),
            $adapter->quoteInto('customer_dob_table.entity_id=main_table.customer_id
             AND customer_dob_table.attribute_id = ?', (int)$dob->getAttributeId()),
            array('customer_dob'=>'value')
        );

    return $this;
}
```